# Limit of functions - always for both sides (+-) necessary?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

I'm very confused when I read some pages on the internet about limits (for functions).

Let's say I got any function f(x) given and someone tells me to find the limit (towards 3 or $\infty$ or whatever...).

I have to do that for both (+-) sides? So I show it for +3 and -3?

It's not enough if I just show it for +3?

Please tell me, this confuses me a lot and I couldn't find an answer to this.

For series, I would use one of these criterias, ratio test as an example. And there, I also don't have to show it for both sides. Or am I wrong? :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limits for $+3$ and $-3$ have nothing to do with each other. The notation you want for limits is $3^+$ and $3^-$ or $-3^+$ and $-3^-$

You are a little confused by the notation. Let's say we want to find the limit of the function for $x \to 3$. Then we need to find the limit for $x \to 3^+$ which means $x$ approaches $3$ from the right side. Then we need to find the limit for $x \to 3^-$ which means $x$ approaches $3$ from the left side. If the limits are equal then we say that $\lim_{x \to 3}$ exists.

In general, when people write $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ they mean that both

$$\lim_{x \to x_0^+} f(x)$$ - from the right side

and

$$\lim_{x \to x_0^-} f(x)$$  - from the left side

exist and are equal. Otherwise no limit $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ exists.

It doesn't matter if $x_0<0$ or $x_0>0$ at all.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Just another question:
What if we got $x \rightarrow  x_{0}$? Then for both sides?

Comment: I've checked L'Hôpitals rule and there it's saying lim x to x_o

Comment: Ahhh so if I see x_0 I need to show it for both sides, yes?
And if there is number, for example 3, then just for one side (+) because 3 is positive, right?

Comment: Ok now I think I understand. When they write lim x to x_0 it's already assumed that both sides +- are equal and thus I have to show it just for one side, right?

Comment: @cnmesr, see the edited answer with all my comments. If you still don;t understand, please consult with a calculus textbook or a teacher

Comment: ok tyvm I solve task now and post, maybe then I understand complete.
Tyvm for your time and help

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If the function is continuous in x, then its left and tight limits (+-, as you call them) are the same. So you do not need to compute them both.

For $\infty$ you do not need it either (as there is no right limit to $+\infty$, for example).

On the other hand, if you want to compute $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{|x|}{x}$, then you have to compute them both. In fact since the function is not continuous in 0, it has NO limit there, only left and right ones.

Comment: The function $|\cdot|$ IS continuous.

Comment: $|x|$ is continuous, it's just not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Sorry guys, you are of course absolutely correct: I wrote |x| and was thinking of a completely different function. I will edit that. Not enough morning coffee apparently.

Comment: What if $x \rightarrow x_{0}$?
Then for both +-?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your comment. If you know the function is continuous in $x_0$, you do not have to compute them both